# Absolutely convergent double series which can not be arranged in a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

Given a double series $\{b_{ij}\}$, $i=1,2,3,\dots$, $j=1,2,3,\dots$, suppose that
$\sum^\infty_{j=1}|b_{ij}|<\infty$ for each $i$ and $\sum^\infty_{i=1}\sum^\infty_{j=1}|b_{ij}|<\infty$. Next, we arrange $\{b_{ij}\}$ in a sequence $\{a_n\}$. Will $\sum a_n$ converge? Is the convergence absolute? Does $\sum a_n=\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}$?

---

To solve a problem in a discrete mathematics textbook, I proved the following

> ***Theorem 1.*** Let $\sum a_n$ be a series of complex numbers which converges absolutely, and let $b(i,j)=a((i+j-2)(i+j-1)/2+j)$. Then $\sum_j |b_{ij}|<\infty$ for each $i$, $\sum_{i,j}|b_{ij}|<\infty$, and $\sum a_n=\sum b_{ij}$.

which can be proved with

> ***Lemma 2.*** Every rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series converges to the same sum.

and

> ***Lemma 3.*** Fix a positive integer $N$. Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_{ij}\}$ be sequences such that $b(i,j)=a((j-1)N+i)$ for $i=1,2,\dots, N$, $j=1,2,3,\dots$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum_j b_{ij}$ converges absolutely for each $i$. In either case, $\sum a_n=\sum_i\sum_jb_{ij}$.

I wonder if the converse of Theorem 1 is also valid.

Comment: is it possible to include your attempt?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the notation becomes consistent? You start out with a sequence $a_{ij}$, then a sequence $b_n$ appears with a very sloppy definition, and suddenly you are talking about $a_n$ and $b_{ij}$, without defining them. Also, what is the relation between the first paragraph and the text below the horizontal line?

Comment: @Thomas "what is the relation between the first paragraph and the text below the horizontal line?" I feel the final sentence explains that pretty nicely. Above the line is the actual question, and below the line is where the question comes from (what we like to call "context" here on math.SE): musing on the converse of a theorem they encountered. Apart from some muddy notation in the motivation section, I feel the question itself is pretty clear, and well motivated, especially considering it's someone's first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will converge. Indeed, we have $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ and absolute convergence. Let $I(n)$ be the largest $i$ that appears as an index of $b$ in $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, and similarly $J(n)$ is the largest $j$. Then
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n |a_k| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{I(n)}\sum_{j = 1}^{J(n)} |b_{ij}| \,\leq\, \sum_{i = 1}^\infty\sum_{j = 1}^\infty |b_{ij}|
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, the rightmost sum doesn't change and stays finite, so the leftmost sum is bounded and monotonic, and therefore must also converge.